# Copy Most Recent Date's row values where gaps in dates exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am creating a report in Tableau for a new product that captures metrics such as previous applications pending, new apps end of day pending etc. In order to do this, I need a a snapshot of the end of day status for each application each day.  A decision was made above my pay grade to only capture a rolling seven day delta of the data.  So, what happens is an application that has not had a status change in the previous seven days stops appearing in the DB until something new happens which allows for gaps in dates and throws my numbers off in my report. What I need is a snapshot for each day for each application, so when there is a date gap, I want to grab the most recent previous day's record and insert to fill in the gaps between the two dates. Also, I join to a credit score table and we sometimes pull all three bureaus, sometimes two, sometimes one so there could be up to three rows per application per day.

I have looked on this site for similar issues which I seem some similar issues however none are an exact match to what I am trying to accomplish and I honestly do not know where to start.  Will a correlated subquery accomplish what I need?  I provided some code below to show what the data looks like currently.

```
drop table if exists #date
drop table if exists #test

create table #date
    (
        calendar_date date
    )

insert into #date
values
('2019-08-07'),
('2019-08-08'),
('2019-08-09'),
('2019-08-10'),
('2019-08-11'),
('2019-08-12')

create table #test
    (
        id int,
        period_date date,
        decision_status varchar(20),
        credit_score int,
        expired_flag bit
    )

insert into #test (id,period_date,decision_status,credit_score,expired_flag)
values
(1,'2019-08-08','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-08','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-09','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-09','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-10','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-10','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-11','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-11','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-12','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-12','declined',642,null),
(2,'2019-08-08','review',656,null),
(2,'2019-08-08','review',648,null),
(2,'2019-08-09','review',656,null),
(2,'2019-08-09','review',648,null),
(2,'2019-08-12','review',656,null),
(2,'2019-08-12','review',648,null),
(3,'2019-08-08','preapproved',678,null),
(3,'2019-08-08','preapproved',689,null),
(3,'2019-08-08','preapproved',693,null),
(3,'2019-08-09','preapproved',678,null),
(3,'2019-08-09','preapproved',689,null),
(3,'2019-08-09','preapproved',693,null),
(3,'2019-08-11','preapproved',678,1),
(3,'2019-08-11','preapproved',689,1),
(3,'2019-08-11','preapproved',693,1),
(3,'2019-08-12','preapproved',678,1),
(3,'2019-08-12','preapproved',689,1),
(3,'2019-08-12','preapproved',693,1),
(4,'2019-08-08','onboarded',725,null),
(4,'2019-08-09','onboarded',725,null),
(4,'2019-08-10','onboarded',725,null),
(5,'2019-08-08','approved',685,null),
(5,'2019-08-08','approved',675,null),
(5,'2019-08-09','approved',685,null),
(5,'2019-08-09','approved',675,null),
(5,'2019-08-12','approved',685,1),
(5,'2019-08-12','approved',675,1)
```

And the query:

```
select id, calendar_date, period_date, decision_status, credit_score, expired_flag
from #date join
     #test
     on calendar_date=dateadd(day,-1,period_date)
order by id, calendar_date
```

I just need each application to show for each day.

Comment: What is an "application"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
After receiving the reply from Gordon, which gave me some inspiration and set me in the right direction, and conducting some additional research, I appear to have found a solution that is working.  I wanted to share the solution here in case anyone else runs across this problem.  I am posting the code below:

```
drop table if exists #date
drop table if exists #test
drop table if exists #test1
drop table if exists #row_num

create table #date
    (
        calendar_date date
    )

insert into #date
values
('2019-08-07'),
('2019-08-08'),
('2019-08-09'),
('2019-08-10'),
('2019-08-11')

create table #test
    (
        id int,
        period_date date,
        decision_status varchar(20),
        credit_score int,
        expired_flag bit
    )

insert into #test (id,period_date,decision_status,credit_score,expired_flag)
values
(1,'2019-08-08','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-08','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-09','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-09','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-10','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-10','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-11','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-11','declined',642,null),
(1,'2019-08-12','declined',635,null),
(1,'2019-08-12','declined',642,null),
(2,'2019-08-08','review',656,null),
(2,'2019-08-08','review',648,null),
(2,'2019-08-09','review',656,null),
(2,'2019-08-09','review',648,null),
(2,'2019-08-12','review',656,null),
(2,'2019-08-12','review',648,null),
(3,'2019-08-08','preapproved',678,null),
(3,'2019-08-08','preapproved',689,null),
(3,'2019-08-08','preapproved',693,null),
(3,'2019-08-09','preapproved',678,null),
(3,'2019-08-09','preapproved',689,null),
(3,'2019-08-09','preapproved',693,null),
(3,'2019-08-11','preapproved',678,1),
(3,'2019-08-11','preapproved',689,1),
(3,'2019-08-11','preapproved',693,1),
(3,'2019-08-12','preapproved',678,1),
(3,'2019-08-12','preapproved',689,1),
(3,'2019-08-12','preapproved',693,1),
(4,'2019-08-08','onboarded',725,null),
(4,'2019-08-09','onboarded',725,null),
(4,'2019-08-10','onboarded',725,null),
(5,'2019-08-08','approved',685,null),
(5,'2019-08-08','approved',675,null),
(5,'2019-08-09','approved',685,null),
(5,'2019-08-09','approved',675,null),
(5,'2019-08-12','approved',685,1),
(5,'2019-08-12','approved',675,1)

select id,calendar_date,decision_status,credit_score,expired_flag
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id,calendar_date order by calendar_date) as row_id
      ,cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id,calendar_date order by calendar_date) as char(1)) as row_num
into #test1
from #date
join #test
    on calendar_date=dateadd(day,-1,period_date)
order by id,calendar_date

create table #row_num
    (
        row_id int,
        row_num char(1)
    )

insert into #row_num
values
(1,'1'),
(2,'2'),
(3,'3')

select i.id 
       ,d.calendar_date
       ,coalesce(t.decision_status,t1.decision_status) as decision_status
       ,coalesce(t.credit_score,t1.credit_score) as credit_score
       ,coalesce(t.expired_flag,t1.expired_flag) as expired_flag
from #date d 
     cross join
     (select distinct id 
      from #test1 ) i
     cross join #row_num r 
     left join #test1 t
        on t.id=i.id
        and t.row_id=r.row_id
        and t.calendar_date=d.calendar_date
     join
     (select id,row_id,decision_status,credit_score,expired_flag
             ,calendar_date as start_date
             ,lead(calendar_date,1,dateadd(day,1,(select max(calendar_date) from #date)))
              over (partition by id,row_id order by calendar_date) as end_date
      from #test1
     ) t1
        on t1.id=i.id
        and t1.row_id=r.row_id
        and d.calendar_date>=t1.start_date
        and d.calendar_date<t1.end_date
order by i.id,d.calendar_date,r.row_id
```

This gives me what I am looking for, all the daily records for each application for each day.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need a `left join`: just need a `left join`:

```
select t.id, d.calendar_date, t.period_date, t.decision_status, t.credit_score, t.expired_flag
from #date d left join
     #test t
     on d.calendar_date = dateadd(day, -1, t.period_date)
order by id, d.calendar_date;
```

If by "application" you mean the `id` in `#test`, then use `cross join` to generate the rows and a `outer apply` to fill in the values:

```
select t.id, d.calendar_date, t.period_date, t.decision_status, t.credit_score, t.expired_flag
from #date d cross join
     (select distinct id from #test) i outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from #test t
      where t.id = i.id and t.date <= d.date
      order by t.date desc
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Unfortunately that does not produce the expected results to what I need.  You will notice from the query I wrote to show what the data may look like in the table that some of the ids have more than one record on the same day due to credit scores being pulled from more than one  credit bureau such as id 1 that has two records each day.  ID 1 in this instance has all days completely filled so those should remain the same however looking at id 2, it also has 2 rows per day but skips from 8/8 to 8/11.  I need to fill in the gaps  with all records from most recent date's values